# Unable to show siteA's content at siteB by domain masking

Tags: .htaccess, domain-mask

I have a domain *www.siteA.com*, which uses Joomla, while the domain *www.siteB.com* is empty.

I would like to show the content of the domain *www.siteA.com* at *www.siteB.com*.

I tried to solve the problem first by making a domain redirection by **.htaccess**, but I could not show SiteA's content at SiteB.

**How can you show the contents of mysiteA.com at mysiteB.com by domain masking in .htaccess?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be doing this by CNAME-ing the domain, but if you really want to use .htaccess you can do what @Unkwntech suggests

Edit: It would just look like

```
www.siteB.com CNAME www.siteA.com
```

Whichever way you do it (CNAME or htaccess) you're probably going to get an SEO penalty for duplicate content.

Comment: How would you do it with CNAME?

Comment: Thank you! The best way seems to be to transfer the content in Site A to Site B. I need to solve the problem of how to change the domain names at mysql databases, since I use Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.siteA.tld/$1 [NC]
```

This should rewrite every request to siteA.